# Prove if $B$ has a smallest element, then this element is unique.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Working on the book: Daniel J. Velleman. "HOW TO PROVE IT: A Structured Approach, Second Edition" (p. 206)

> Theorem 4.4.6. Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$, and $B \subseteq A$.
>
> If $B$ has a smallest element, then this smallest element is unique. Thus, we
>   can speak of the smallest element of $B$ rather than a smallest element.

I symbolized "$B$ has a smallest element", as: $$\exists y\forall x(x \in B \to (y,x) \in R)$$

"$B$ smallest element is unique", as: $$\exists y(\forall x(x \in B \to (y,x) \in R) \land \forall z(\forall x(x \in B \to (z,x) \in R) \to y = z))$$

My proof skeleton using Fitch-style natural deduction:

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{1.\, \exists y\forall x(x \in B \to (y,x) \in R)}{
 \fitch{2.\, \forall x(x \in B \to (b',x) \in R)}{
 \fitch{3.\, \forall x(x \in B \to (b,x) \in R)}{
   4.\,b \in B \to (b',b) \in R \Ae{2}
   5.\,b \in B \to (b,b') \in R \Ae{3}
   \vdots\\
}\\
b=b'\\
}\\
\forall x(x \in B \to (z,x) \in R) \to y = z)
}
$

As $R$ is a partial order, I would need to use *antisymmetry* property. But I do not know how to use it in lines 4,5 to infer that $(b',b) \in R \land (b,b') \in R$.

How can I fill the dots ? Am I missing some premise or step?

Comment: Your representation of "$B$ has a smallest element" is missing an important part.  It should be

$$\exists y(y \in B \land \forall x(x \in B \to (y,x) \in R))$$  Using your representation, there's no reason such a $y$ would be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, @Brian Moehring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Preliminary:* I use the notation $xRy$ for $(x,y) \in R$.

*Remark:* The correct formalization of "$B$ has a smallest element" is 
$$\exists y(y \in B \land \forall x(x \in B \to yRx))$$
It is important that smallest element of $B$ is in $B$, otherwise you lose uniqueness. Indeed, let $A = \{a_1, a_2, b\}$ and $ B = \{b\}$ with $a_1 < b$ and $a_2 < b$ and $a_1 \neq a_2$: both $a_1$ and $a_2$ (which are distinct) satisfy $\exists y \forall x (x \in B \to yRx)$ (I assume the domain of quantifications is $A$).

*Solution:* First, consider the following proof $\pi$ in Fitch-style natural deduction of the fact that if $R$ is a antisymmetric relation (on the domain $A$, premise $0$) and if $y$ is a smallest element of $B$ (premise $1$), then any other smallest element of $B$ is equal to $y$.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{0. \, \forall y \forall z (yRz \land zRy \to y = z)
 \\
  1.\, y \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to yRx)}
{
 \fitch{2.\, z \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to zRx)}
    {3. \, \forall x (x \in B \to zRx) \ce{2}
     4. \, y \in B \to z R y \Ae{3}
     5. \, y \in B \ce{1}
     6. \, zRy \ie{4,5}
     7. \, \forall x (x \in B \to yRx) \ce{1}
     8. \, z \in B \to yRz \Ae{7}
     9. \, z \in B \ce{2}
    10. \, yRz \ie{8,9}
    11. \, yRz \land zRy \ci{10, 6}
    12. \, yRz \land zRy \to y = z \Ae{0}
    13. \, y = z \ie{12,11}
}\\
 14. \, (z \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to zRx)) \to y = z \ii{2{-}13}
 15. \, \forall z \big((z \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to zRx)) \to y = z \big) \Ai{14}
}
$

Given the proof $\pi$ above, it is immediate to write a proof in Fitch-style natural deduction of 
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\exists y \big( y \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to yRx) \land \forall z ((z \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to zRx)) \to y = z) \big)
\end{equation}
under the assumptions that $R$ is antisymmetric (premise $0$ below) and that $B$ has a smallest element (premise $1$ below):

$
\fitch{0. \, \forall y \forall z (yRz \land zRy \to y = z)
 \\
  1.\, \exists y (y \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to yRx))}
{
 \fitch{2.\, y \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to yRx)}{
    \vdots \ \pi
    \\
    16. \, \forall z \big((z \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to zRx)) \to y = z \big) \\
    17. \, (y \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to yRx)) \land \forall z \big((z \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to zRx)) \to y = z \big) \ci{2, 16}
    18. \, \exists y \big( (y \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to yRx)) \land \forall z \big((z \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to zRx)) \to y = z \big) \big) \Ei{17}
    }\\
  19. \, \exists y \big( (y \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to yRx)) \land \forall z \big((z \!\in\! B \land \forall x (x \!\in\! B \to zRx)) \to y = z \big) \big) \Ee{1, 2{-}18}
}
$

Note that formula $(*)$ above formalizes the sentence "$B$ has a unique smallest element".

*Final remark:* Actually the derivation above shows that only antisymmetry of $R$ is required to prove the uniqueness of the smallest element. Transitivity and reflexivity of $R$ play no role.

Comment: Spectacular. Thank you very much, @Taroccoesbrocco. I wish I could accept this answer two times :-)

Comment: I really liked how you “modularised” this proof. Could you tell me what is needed to do it ? In order to insert a proof into a bigger proof, do I need to have exact premises ? I will appreciate if you could elaborate a little on this.

Comment: @F.Zer - You're welcome! The symbol $\vdots \ \pi$ means the you have to take the proof $\pi$ above and replace the vertical dots in the second derivation with $\pi$. Note that above $\vdots$ you have exactly premise $1$ in $\pi$ and above $\vdots$ you have exactly the conclusion of $\pi$ (otherwise you couldn't plug $\pi$ into the second derivation). To be more precise, you just have to plug the part of $\pi$ from premise $1$ to conclusion $15$ (discarding premise $0$ of $\pi$) into the second derivation, since premise $0$ of $\pi$ is exactly premise $0$ of the second derivation.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's a great method. I was studying your explanation and wondered about something.

Comment: In $\pi$, you provided a proof of this sequent: $$\forall y \forall z (yRz \land zRy \to y = z), y \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to yRx)\vdash \forall z \big((z \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to zRx)) \to y = z \big)$$

Comment: Do you think would be good if $\pi$ was a "stand-alone" proof that could be inserted in _any_ proof ? So, adding $\big(\forall y \forall z (yRz \land zRy \to y = z) \land y \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to yRx)\big) \to \forall z \big((z \in B \land \forall x (x \in B \to zRx)) \to y = z)\big)$ as a premise, enables the use of  _Universal elimination_ and _Implication Elimination_.

Comment: Something along this lines: [Link to proof](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpjwx103mk1wa5i/screen%20shot%202020-05-28%20at%2018.33.26.png?dl=0)

Comment: @F.Zer - Yes and no. Sure, a modular approach is good when you have to use  the same subproof several times, or if you want to "enucleate" a piece of proof from the rest to stress something. But in this case there is a technical problem: a premise of $\pi$ is _open_ ($y$ is not bound to any quantifier), hence the proof $\pi$ talks about a generic $y$. So, if you want to combine $\pi$ with another _existential_ axiom, you have to be careful (remember the constraint about the elimination of the existential quantifier).

Comment: @F.Zer - I guess in the [proof you linked](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpjwx103mk1wa5i/Screen%20Shot%202020-05-28%20at%2018.33.26.png?dl=0) you can't prove anything interesting because your premise $2$ is open ($y$ is not bound) and hence you can't use premises $0$ and $1$ with _modus ponens_. And you can't use elimination of $\exists$ on premise $0$ with $y$ exactly because $y$ is free in premise $2$.

Comment: You are right, @Taroccoesbrocco ! My proof is incorrect in many aspects. Thank you !